# MySQL Select data from a row

Tags: php, mysql

i got this code

```
if($_GET['action'] == 'test')
        {

            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = {$_GET['id']}";
            $result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($dbc));


        }
```

And now i want to output a text like
Username: Martijn (That's the user_name from ID 1)
Reg date: 01/01/2015

But i can't get that working. I checked many stackoverflow questions but couldnt find it. Here you can see the website: http://admincontrol.martijnmelchers.nl/show_profile.php?action=test&id=1

Comment: Step 1, remove the error suppressing `@` in `@mysqli_query`.

Comment: So `$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($dbc));`

Comment: Your page says undefined variable `row`. Where is your `while()` code?

Comment: I don't have a `while()` code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You don't need that error suppressiong there*

This is usually in the third page in PHP-MySQL tutorials.

You have to add to your code, after the `$result...` line:

```
while($row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

 echo "<p> Username" . $row['user_name'] . " - Reg Date" . $row['reg_date'] . " .</p>";

}
```

Comment: Thank you very munch! I'll make it the answer when i can :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mysqli_fetch_array function for this.

```
if($_GET['action'] == 'test')
{
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = {$_GET['id']}";
        $result = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($dbc));
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
}
echo $row["Username"];
```

You'd  have to replace Username with whatever your field name is in the database.